# "Insufficient HTTPS Coverage" in Google Search Console... for pages that are being redirected to HTTPS

Tags: google-search-console, https, http

I'm getting an "Insufficient HTTPS coverage on your site" error in my domain property in Google Page Experience, which is strange because my entire site uses HTTPS and has done so for a long time. So I go and search for HTTP only URLs in my site... but the only ones that Google shows me are pages that already have HTTPS versions. For example: if my site is https://example.com, Google is showing me http://example.com as an HTTP page in my site.

Now, all my HTTP URLs are redirected using 301 to the proper HTTPS ones, and have been for a long time. The only thing I didn't do was to remove my HTTP site property when I migrated years ago; I just added a new HTTPS site property.

What do I do now with Google's warning? Do I ignore it? Do I remove the HTTP property?

Comment: In which section of Google search console is this message appearing?   Can you provide a screenshot?  Does Google show anything other than this message for explanation?  Is the a link to a help document with the message?  If so, please share the link.

Comment: It's in my domain property, in the "Page Experience" section. There's a  "Learn more" link that opens a popup in the same page, so I can't copy the URL, but the text says: "A page must be served over HTTPS to be eligible for Good page experience status. The Page Experience report doesn't consider HTTPS criteria when calculating URL status, only as a site-wide warning: if your site has a relatively high percentage of HTTP URLs, you will see a Failing warning in the Page Experience report" etc., etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This message means that Google doesn't have enough "field data" collected from users of your website to give you page experience information.

[On Twitter Google's John Mueller says](https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/1387874087045844996) that this message is misleading:

> Unfortunately there's a bug there in Search Console. When we we show "Failing / Insufficient HTTPS coverage" in the Page experience report, that can just mean we don't have the full data (instead of saying "not enough data" we incorrectly say "failing"). We're fixing it.

There is nothing wrong with your site, and nothing you need to fix.